# How do I add the hashmark syntax in the URL with click events in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url, load

I'm trying to set the URL to follow the AJAX crawling scheme as described by google: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174993

As an exampe when a user clicks the Advanced Search menu option the jquery call looks like this:

```
$('#search_advanced').click(function(e) {

    var no_cache = new Date().getTime();

    $('#main').load("search_advanced.php?cache=" + no_cache, function () {    
        $.ajax({ url: "js/search_advanced.js", dataType: "jsonp" });
    });

    return false;

});
```

My current URL doesn't change so if the user refreshes the page they get the page they were on prior to the call which in this case would be:

mysite/home.php

I am trying to set the URL to be:

mysite/#!/search=advanced

I need the ability to call these URLs directly and have them generate the correct page.

ANy thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for addressing.

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: Looks like that would do the trick...I was hoping for an easier solution :)